# appinstalled event is not triggering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, progressive-web-apps

I made a PWA which uses the `beforeinstallprompt` event to trigger the 'installation process' when the user clicks the 'install' button. This event is working properly but the `appinstalled` event is not firing at all.

I have a component in a Vue app, which I want to be rendered only if the user doesn't have my PWA installed already. I am trying to use the `appinstalled` event to determine this.

```js
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  deferredPrompt = e;
})

window.addEventListener('appinstalled', () => {
    isInstalled.value = true
})

async function install() {
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    const { outcome } = await deferredPrompt.userChoice;
    if (outcome === 'accepted') {
        deferredPrompt = null;
        isInstalled.value = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your first sentence.

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: As English, it doesn't really make sense at all. I don't think it's even correct English. What is named what? What is triggering what?

Comment: The event "appinstalled" does not work for me. In fact, it should fire when the browser notices that the user has already installed the PWA application. But even if the application is installed, the event does not fire.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Based on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/appinstalled_event), I think `appinstalled` only fires when the app is actually installed, not on every load. You can probably use Service Worker events instead...

Comment: You can detect the different lifecycle stages based on the specific combination and sequence of events emitted. You could probably handcode for this case, but almost anything with Service Workers gets hairy fast. "Use the WorkBox", to quote the [Service Workies game](https://serviceworkies.com) (highly recommend).